# Android, Multiple Searchable Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, searchview

How can I make two different searchable activities?

I have different search logic in different parts of my app (what I am searching and how I'm displaying the results).

For example, in some activities I wish to query my online database for objects of class A, and in another activity I wish to query my online database for objects of class B.

I currently have a searchable activity setup from following the guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html , and works great for searching for objects of class A. However, I couldn't figure out how to make a second searchable activity that has a different layout and query logic. It seems you can only apply the searchable metadata to one activity?

There must be a way to do this, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it.

If you want to have only one default search activity in your app, and other multiple activities sending search query to it, you can supply app search metadata while creating search view in your specific activity like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Search Type", "local search");
    bundle.putString("Other metadata", "metadata");

    searchView.setAppSearchData(bundle);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
}
```

Then getting the app search metadata in default search activity like below:

```
        mSearchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);

        // Get the type of search to perform
        mSearchType = bundle.getString("Search Type");
```

Comment: setAppSearchData is not a public method of support SearchView or framework's SearchView. It uses a @RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP) annotation and is not documented. Is there a documented way to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

In each activity you want to search from override the options menus like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_search_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    if (searchManager != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
    return true;
}

// Override onOptionsItemSelected and onSearchRequested() adds additional data to intent
// If you have several activities that use the SearchableActivity, override these methods to
// add contextual data. You can even modify the searchEvent by using the constructor -
// onSearchRequested(SearchEvent se))
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString(SearchableActivity.TAG, MainActivity.TAG);
    startSearch(null, false, b, false);
    return true;
}
```

This is documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchDialog
And the above is a working example. Of course this assumes you've set everything else up properly. Hope this helps.